# Handling a combination of async callouts, schedulable jobs, and queueable jobs

Tags: callout, scheduled-apex, asynchronous, architecture, queueable-apex

The current requirements for my system is as follows:

1. When a certain change is saved on the `Account` object, I need to create an `Order` object and make a callout to Service A.
2. Service A finishes processing at some point in time, and the only way to tell if it's done is to make a verification check. Once it's verified, I need to make callouts to 6 different services (B, C, D, E, F, G) to notify them of the response.

The current bottleneck is that every single service from A-G are asynchronous, which caused me to use a combination of future callouts, scheduled jobs, and queueable jobs.

The way the system currently works is that after the `Order` object is created and the callout to Service A is made, I have a scheduled job running every 5 minutes that will check every incomplete `Order` object and verify with Service A.

Once verification from Service A is received, the `Order` object is modified, which then fires the `Order` trigger. The trigger will then need to make 6 callouts, which I put in a Queue.

Previously, it was guaranteed that there would only be one incomplete `Order` object at a time in the system, but that is no longer going to be true. However, when there are more than one `Order` object's trigger getting fired, I run into the governor limit of only one queueable job being allowed to exist at a time.

Is there anyway around this? Or will I have to rearchitect the whole thing? Everything is already kind of convoluted because of the need to do DML statements with the callouts, so I'm making `insert` and `update` statements in unintuitive places (in the queueable handler). I'm almost considering just spinning up an AWS server or something to handle the 6 asynchronous callouts, but then I would have to deal with security issues and that's more trouble than it's worth right now.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Here is the current error message I get:
`12:28:04:805 FATAL_ERROR System.LimitException: Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2`
The stack trace points that this error happens on the line where I run 'System.enqueueJob(new PbxQueueableJobs());`The line that caused the error is in a trigger that is fired due to a mass update of two`Order`objects. The error was caused by the second`Order` object's trigger.

Comment: take a look at Advanced Apex book 4th edition for a scalable async pattern

Answer (score 1):

The limit you're seeing is that in async transaction context you can only add one job to the queue with `System.enqueueJob`. `Queueable` jobs can be chained and chaining works regardless of whether a job does or does not do a callout.

From the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm):

> To run a job after some other processing is done first by another job,
> you can chain queueable jobs. To chain a job to another job, submit
> the second job from the execute() method of your queueable class. You
> can add only one job from an executing job, which means that only one
> child job can exist for each parent job. For example, if you have a
> second class called `SecondJob` that implements the `Queueable` interface,
> you can add this class to the queue in the `execute()` method as
> follows:
>
> ```
> public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
>       public void execute(QueueableContext context) { 
>         // Chain this job to next job by submitting the next job
>         System.enqueueJob(new SecondJob());
>       } 
> }
> ```

If you implement one Queueable job per target (B-G), you should be able to fire them in a chain and stay under one queued job per async transaction limit.

You should also take a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for possible rearchitecture ideas.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I'm currently not having an issue having Services B-G run. My issue is coming up because I'm getting multiple instances of Service A spawning multiple "queued" calls to Services B-G.

What I mean is that when an `Order` gets triggered, it calls B-G. Previously, when only one `Order` gets modified at a time, this was fine. But now multiple `Order` objects are getting modified at once.

Comment: From your question: _I run into the governor limit of only one queueable job being allowed to exist at a time_. That is a per async transaction limit. It would apply regardless of how many `Order` instances are processed - one or many. Perhaps you're running into a different limit? It would be helpful to see a 
a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and the code or metadata to reproduce the problem. (Please edit your post).

Comment: I edited my post. It still sounds a little confusing, so let me know if I can clarify in any way. It does seem like I'm running into some scalability issues as @cropredy mentioned.

Comment: It's not enough information to say what's going on. With technically complex questions such as yours, it helps to have enough code + metadata for an MVR (minimum viable reproduction).